# Fllnk jobmanager download jar files in /tmp directory

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have some problems with my apache flink stream system.
A few days ago, we detect that flink was using too much space in the hard disk, and explorint them, we found to many (around a thousand) `.jar` files in `/tmp` directory on jobmanager container.

The .jar files always have a similar name, but with diferent numbers:

- 1695477181_3183563526079495551lib_org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar
- 1798263280_2346102789822957064lib_com.google.protobuf_2.6.0.jar

The .jar files was created when I use the 'Submit New Job' menu

[image]

In this menu, flink start to polling `GET http://myflink:myport/jars/` (once at second).
For each request, a couple of .jar files are created.

I can't find any information about this and I'm not sure if its a bug or something. Any help please ?

My installations:

- Flink 1.12.1 running with docker swarm
- Flink 1.7 running with docker compose
- Flink 1.14.4 java 11 running with docker-compose

The three installations have the same problem

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a Flink problem. It is caused for a external dependency, exacly this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.kura</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.kura.core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.300</version>
</dependency>
```

When I remove this dependency from pom, the problem stops.